# Javascript browser navigator permissions else section not triggering

Tags: javascript, html, web, browser, navigator

Have a small javascript piece of code which calls `navigator.geolocation`.

I have an `if` statement, which works, to show the latitude and longitude if the user the user allows the call. However, the `else` section is not running.

If I run the code below I get prompted by the browser to allow; if I allow it then coordinates are shown. However, if I hit block instead nothing happens even though there is an `else` section.

```
<body>
  <br> <p id="ChangeSring">Test</p>
  <script>
  var x = document.getElementById("ChangeSring");
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(SavePosition);
  } else { 
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
      document.cookie = 'location=false;path=/form_handler';
  }

  function SavePosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    document.cookie = 'location=true;path=/form_handler';
    document.cookie = 'latitude='+ position.coords.latitude +';path=/form_handler';
    document.cookie = 'longitude='+ position.coords.longitude +';path=/form_handler';
  }
  </script>

  <form action="/form_handler" _lpchecked="1">
    Enter value:
    <input type="text" name="SomeVar"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="search">
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you looked at console logs? anything useful there?

Comment: i think that else statement is only getting called if the browser doesn’t support it, not if blocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `else` to check for permissions.

The navigator method [`getCurrentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) takes a success and error callbacks.
The error callback will be called if permission is denied.

```js
if (navigator.geolocation) { // this checks if navigator is supported at all
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(console.log, () => {
    console.log('Permission denied')
  });
} else {
  console.log('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

getCurrentPosition takes a `success` and an `error` function.
Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition#Example

```
function errorGettingPosition(positionError) {
  x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  document.cookie = 'location=false;path=/form_handler';
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(SavePosition, errorGettingPosition)
```

Answer (score 0):

That if-else statement is checking if navigator.geolocation it's not undefined(and it's not even if you don't want the browser to know your location) follow the other answers to properly handle permission